# How to make jwt check global

Tags: reactjs, django

I am adding authoraziation with jwt in react for frontend and django for the backend.

When an access token expires I refresh it using axios interceptors. If the refresh token expires then the user logs out. I store the tokens in localStorage and to log out the user I just delete them.

**useAxios.js**

```
....
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async req => {
    
        const user = jwt_decode(authTokens.access)
        const isExpired = dayjs.unix(user.exp).diff(dayjs()) < 1;

        console.log(isExpired)
    
        if(!isExpired) return req
        
    
        const response = await axios.post(`${baseURL}/token/refresh/`, {
            refresh: authTokens.refresh
          }).catch(err=>localStorage.clear())

    
        localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(response.data))
        
        setAuthTokens(response.data)
        setUser(jwt_decode(response.data.access))
        
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.access}`

        return req
    })
```

I have also a file called **AuthContext.js** where the function to login the user is and where the tokens are made. To pass functions I am doing it with context.

I just wrap ``AuthProvider``` to the routes I  want to pass context at App.js

**Home.js**

```
...
let api = useAxios()

    let getUser = async () => {
      let response = await api.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/a/')
      console.log(response.data)
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.data)
      }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log('hey')
      getUser()
    },[])
...
```

So basically when the user enters the home page I am sending a request in django where you need to be authenticated to have access. So if the user's refresh token has expired then I log him out.

**The problem is**

that I don't want to write the `getUser` function for every single page  to check the token.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to wrap the page component with a parent component, like a `PrivateRoute`, which will check the authentication first then render the current page component.

In `PrivateRoute` component, you just need to run `getUser` as before:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({children}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  let api = useAxios()

  let getUser = async () => {
    let response = await api.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/a/')
    console.log(response.data)
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log(response.data)
    }
    // set to false after api call finished.
    // if the user is expired, do the log out things.
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('hey')
    getUser()
  },[])

  // render a temporary content until the api call finished and user is not expired.
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  // render the children component.
  return children
}
```

In the router file it will look like this:

```
// ...other route content.
<PrivateRoute>
  <HomePage />
</PrivateRoute>
// ...other route content.
<PrivateRoute>
  <OtherPage />
</PrivateRoute>
// ...other route content.
```

So every time user directs to each page, it will check the authentication token first, then render current page, like `HomePage`.